# After performing an action by octokit with OAuth app, how to show OAuth app name instead of github username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-api, octokit

I have registered a GitHub OAuth app under my personal GitHub account, and using octokit I am making an automation app.

When octokit perform any action let's say add label to issue, then GitHub says:

**"anmol-kumar0815" added label**, instead of **AutomatedApp added label**.
[image]

PS: "anmol-kumar0815" is my github username and "AutomatedApp" is the name of my OAuth app.

I want github to display "AutomatedApp added a label." but github display's "anmol-kumar0815 added a label".

Here is my code:

```
def client
  @_client ||= Octokit::Client.new(bearer_token: github_access_token, auto_paginate: true)
end

def labels(repo_full_name)
  client.labels(repo_full_name)
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want github to display "AutomatedApp added a label." but github display's "anmol-kumar0815 added a label".

Comment: edit your question -- comments are not permament